# How do I overload TYPE* conversion from another pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion, implicit

I can't seem to find anything that deals with this type of operation.

I have a `class TextButton : public TextDecorator` class that I want to overload the implicit conversion operator for. The `TextButton` class contains a `BasicButton` pointer that I want to give access to.

Overloading the TYPE conversion operator works fine, however it doesn't do what I want it to do when I am using a `TextButton*` to perform the cast on.

This code shows what I mean :

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;



class A {
public :
   void DoThis() {cout << "a is " << this << endl;}
};



class B {
   A* a;

public :
   B() : a(new A) {
      cout << "a is " << a << endl << endl;
   }
   ~B() {delete a;}
   operator A*() {return a;}
};



int main(int argc , char** argv) {

   B b;

   A* a1 = (A*)b;/// Implicit conversion works fine for objects of type B
   A* a2 = (A*)&b;/// Implicit conversion works, but is incorrect for objects of type B*

   A* a3 = static_cast<A*>(b);/// Fine, not what I want

///   A* a4 = static_cast<A*>(&b);/// What I want, but illegal
/// "invalid static cast from B* to A*"

   a1->DoThis();
   a2->DoThis();
   a3->DoThis();
///   a4->DoThis();

   return 0;
}
```

The output ((un)luckily it didn't crash) shows why it is bad :

```
c:\ctwoplus\progcode\test\Cast>cast.exe
a is 0xea1718

a is 0xea1718
a is 0x61ff20
a is 0xea1718
```

So what I want is to make this possible :

```
TextButton* tb = MakeTextButton(...);
BasicButton* button_access = (BasicButton*)tb;
```

And have it work correctly.

Ideas?

Comment: inhert TextButton from BasicButton?

Comment: BasicButton inherits from WidgetBase and so does TextDecorator indirectly. If I do that I end up with the dreaded inheritance diamond.

Comment: @MarcD: then use `virtual` inheritance, or consider if `TextDecorator` actually needs to inherit from `WidgetBase`.

Comment: TextDecorator inherits from WidgetDecorator, which inherits from WidgetBase. It does this so I can use any number of different decorators on top of any other widget. virtual inheritance is not correct in this case, as the TextButton needs to be an independent widget, and so does its TextDecorator base. I just don't want to deal with the mess that diamond inheritance causes.

Comment: I suppose the only correct thing to do in this case is to provide a member function which returns the correct pointer. It turns out I decided to inherit from BasicButton after all, so that dynamic_cast will work. I just wanted to avoid the work of overriding all the different functions in WidgetBase just to forward them to another object that is responsible for the actual work. That's probably for another topic though. Although I don't understand why you can't overload global conversion operators to do this. It would help in forwarding functions immensely.